# Get specific word and following text

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, grep, string

Input File

```
Mar 21 13:25:04 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[5857]: v2LKMUDq005855: to=<dirdel@gmail.com>,<jhk@hotmail.com>, delay=00:02:34, xdelay=00:02:34, mailer=esmtp, pri=151745, relay=icadmed-com.mail.p...ction.googlemail.com. [xxx.xx.xxx.xxx], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<5c847a983008319fdd71bc81b60daef7@dmgnc.radionhub.com> [InternalId=76295799050449, Hostname=BY1PR0701MB1752.namprd07.prod.gmail.com] 8962 bytes in 0.961, 9.102 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Mar 21 11:34:55 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[5478]: v2LIXc00005476: to=<delivery@gmail.com>, delay=00:01:17, xdelay=00:01:17, mailer=esmtp, pri=120883, relay=gmail-com.mail.p...ction.googlemail.com. [xxx.xx.xxx.xx], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<7bb6f30a4ba05ffab3bad46b7a51620b@roshdieh.radionhub.com> [InternalId=79285096289546, Hostname=CY1PR07MB1448.namprd07.prod.googlemail.com] 8049 bytes in 0.226, 34.732 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Mar 20 13:45:16 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[1295]: v2KKfjCN001293: to=<abc@yahoo.com>, delay=00:03:31, xdelay=00:03:31, mailer=esmtp, pri=120883, relay=mta5.am0.yahoodns.net. [xx.xxx.xx.xx], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (ok dirdel)
Mar 20 08:54:57 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[32712]: v2KFss7V032710: to=<xyz@hotmail.com>, delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:03, mailer=esmtp, pri=120892, relay=mx4.hotmail.com. [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent ( <fbdaef9668d4308008be663d52cf2c8d@isc.radionhub.com> Queued mail for delivery)
```

and Expected Output for each line i detect delay more than 1 minutes

```
sendmail[5857]: delay=00:02:34 Hostname=BY1PR0701MB1752.namprd07.prod.gmail.com]
sendmail[5478]: delay=00:01:17 Hostname=CY1PR07MB1448.namprd07.prod.googlemail.com]
sendmail[1295]: delay=00:03:31
```

how can I solve this using a shell script?

Comment: You edited this - if the lines don't have `Hostname`, do you still want the `delay`? If it's less than one minute do you not want the line at all? Please show us the exact output you want for the whole sample.

Comment: i edited this quetion ...i want Hostname,delay and Sendmail values specified in output .....if delay time is less than 60 seconds. if there is no hostname in line i still want delay along with sendmail value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is no longer a sed option. you must parse string where time is `00:01:00`, `00:10:00` or `01:00:07` to count more that 60s.

I came up with a awk file

```
 { result = "" ;
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
     if ( $i ~ /^delay=/ ) {
       s=split(substr($i,6) ,A,":") ;
       t=60*A[1]+A[2] ;
       #printf "%2d : %d mn (60x%s+%s) : %s\n",i,t,A[1],A[2],$i ;
       if ( !t  ) next ;
       result = $i ;
     }
     if ( $i ~ /^Hostname/ ) result = result $i ;

  }
  if ( result != "" ) print result ;
}
```

some hint :

- `( $i ~ /^foo/ )` match i-th field with foo (`^`: start of pattern)
- `split(substr($i,6) ,A,":")` split H:M:S part in array A
- `A = B C` : concatenate string B and C to A

with today's sample this give (`u` being your file name, `u.awk` being file that hold awk program)

```
 awk -f u.awk u
delay=00:02:34, Hostname=BY1PR0701MB1752.namprd07.prod.gmail.com]
delay=00:01:17, Hostname=CY1PR07MB1448.namprd07.prod.googlemail.com]
delay=00:03:31,
```

Comment: I forgot to add sendmail column, this is left as an exercice to reader.

Answer (score 2):

a job for sed

```
sed -e 's|^.* \(delay=[^ ]*\) .*\(Hostname=[^ ]*\) .*$|\1 \2|'  file
```

where

- `sed -e 's| ....l... | ... r ...|'` tell sed to substitue left hand side, by right hand side.
- `^.*  .* .*$` fetch pattern (`.` is any char, `*` any number, sapce is space, `$` is end of line)
- `\(delay=[^ ]*\) \(Hostname=[^ ]*\)` grab pattern with field (and get them numbered)
- `\1 \2` replace what we have found.

**edit**: getting rid of comma

```
sed -e 's|^.* \(delay=[^,]*\), .*\(Hostname=[^ ]*\) .*$|\1 \2|' u
```

where

- use `-i` (`sed -i -s ...`) to edit file in place

Comment: +1, but watch out for the comma - I don't think they want it

Comment: not working with this command giving full line as it is ....there is multiple llines

Comment: is there any other solution for multiple line

Comment: @MaheshPhate Please reformat your input file to represent it as you seem to have it in real life. `sed` can concatenate lines first, but we need to know what the file really looks like.

Comment: yes i have updated quetion

Comment: that' change a lot !! you want to show only delay where delay are above 60s ?

Comment: yes i i want show delay are above 60s

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
awk '{split($8,a,/=|:/);time_taken=a[2]*3600+a[3]*60+a[4]+0;if(time_taken>60){print $5,$8,$18}}' your_file.txt
```

- `split($8,a,/=|:/);` split the 8th column and calculate the seconds.
- compare the time with 60 seconds `if(time_taken>60)`
- print the results `{print $5,$8,$18}`

Answer (score 0):

> We use negative lookahead in Perl regex to get the delays > 1 min

```
perl -lane '
   BEGIN{
      $,=$";
      $dly=qr/\bdelay=(?!00:(?:00:[0-5][0-9]|01:00))(?:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(?=,)/;
   }
   /$dly/ and print /\b(?:Hostname|sendmail)\S+|$dly/g;
' yourfile

sed -e '
   # logic for selecting entries where delay > 1 min
   /[ ]delay=[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],/!d
   /[ ]delay=[0][0]:[0][0]:[0-5][0-9],/d
   /[ ]delay=[0][0]:[0][1]:[0][0],/d

   # we are here => delay > 1 min, now fish out the entries...
   s/^/\n\n/
      s/[ ]sendmail[^ ]*/\n&\n/;  s/\(\n\n.*\)\n\(.*\)\n/\2\1/
      s/[ ]delay=[^, ]*/\n&\n/;   s/\(\n\n.*\)\n\(.*\)\n/\2\1/
      s/[ ]Hostname=[^ ]*/\n&\n/; s/\(\n\n.*\)\n\(.*\)\n/\2\1/
   s/\n\n.*//;s/^\s*//
' yourfile
```

## Output

```
sendmail[5857]: delay=00:02:34 Hostname=BY1PR0701MB1752.namprd07.prod.gmail.com]
sendmail[5478]: delay=00:01:17 Hostname=CY1PR07MB1448.namprd07.prod.googlemail.com]
sendmail[1295]: delay=00:03:31
```